# spring boot azure deployment with github action failed

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, azure-devops, deployment, web-deployment

I hope you go well ,
i'm trying to deploy my full stack application to azure so i'm using the Github Actions !
The probleme that i'm facing is that the project wouldn't build after generating the YAML file while the deployment !
here is the output error :

[github output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4Tjx.png)

I've also created a MySql service and configuring the properties

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://hazem.mysql.database.azure.com.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/demo?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=spring@hazem
spring.datasource.password=mypassword

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

this is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.restuarent</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecommerce</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ecommerce</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Perhaps the yaml file generated is the key point.
From the callstack, it's some mysql connection creation issue.

Comment: 1. Configure a firewall rule for your MySQL server  2. If you provide the wrong URL, database password or wrong db name, you may get Access to Dialectresolutioninfo that cannot be null when ‘hibernate.dialect’ is not set....  3. Make sure you are provinding correct dialect information in application.properties file(Info- Hibernate determines the correct dialect automatically). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-data-jpa-with-azure-mysql

Comment: How to ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.